# change font size of barchart text mpandroidchart

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, charts, mpandroidchart

i tried changing the text size of values in barchart of mpandroidchart using following method

```
barChart.getXAxis().setTextSize(5f);
```

but it dint work.

Comment: Hi, please mention here you wanna change to axis text size or any other textsize in chart and please here give code snippest how you change textsize.

Answer (score 0):

Copy this code snippet into the Chart.java file of the library and use it:

```
/**
     * Sets the font size of the values that are drawn inside the chart.
     * 
     * @param size
     */
    public void setValueTextSize(float size) {
        mValuePaint.setTextSize(Utils.convertDpToPixel(size));
    }
```

Then call **`mChart.setValueTextSize(...)`** whenever you need it.

Comment: it's a paint object Paint mValuPaint = mChart.getPaint(Chart.PAINT_VALUES);

Answer (score 0):

Try This One, Its Working.

```
barChart.getBarData().setValueTextSize(10f);
```